# Android In-app Currency

Tags: android

I have recently started working on an android project and i was wondering if there is a Pre-exsiting way of implementing in app currency e.g coins or diamonds because i wanted to allow the user to use certain features of the app depending on the amount or value of the the currency the user has.Such as enabling or disabling buttons.From what i have learned so far i would use a new database and store a data value in  a file there but I'm not to sure so 
I have come here an asked because i have searched the internet and have had no luck in finding a way to do it and thanks for help in advanced.

Comment: Would someone please point me in the right direction or post an answer it would greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this [library](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary), those guys did a great work there.

Comment: Is that a library or a project because i am looking for an easy way to implement currency because i am not very experienced in java

Comment: @user2254087 This is library and trust me, this is the most easiest thing in compare to Google tutorial.